# date format picture ends before converting entire input string in where condition

Tags: oracle

I want to fetch date part from date/time column in where condtion like this where trucn(ChangeRequestDate) = TO_DATE(sysdate) but trunc function doesnt work in Business objects and when i am TO_DATE in pplace of trucn it is giving me error:
date format picture ends before converting entire  input string

Comment: sysdate is already a date type.  Why are you calling TO_DATE on it?  Please show ACTUAL code.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off using between instead of applying a function to your table column values.

```
ChangeRequestDate BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)
```

Or, since BETWEEN is inclusive on both sides

```
ChangeRequestDate >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND ChangeRequestDate < TRUNC(SYDATE+1)
```